# Obtaining cellid on any gsm enabled cell phone programmatically

Tags: c++, mobile, cellid

Is there a way one can obtain the cellid of a gsm phone programmatically in c++?.

Answer (score 0):

We can only access the cellid of a Sony Ericsson device. I did it through J2ME.
We can't access the cellid of any other device.